# Can't find module Test.HUnit

Tags: haskell, hunit

I am trying to make some unit tests in Haskell and this is basically what I have done in my code:

```
module Test where
import Test.HUnit
test = TestList [TestLabel "running all the tests!"
$ TestList [
. . . . .
]]  

run = runTestTT tests
```

When I try to compile it with the gchi I get this message:

```
 Could not find module ‘Test.HUnit’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none
```

How can I make HUnit work?

I am using GHCi version 7.8.3

Thanks

### Edit:

I tried installing HUnit through cabal as an answer suggested but then I got the error:

```
Could not find module ‘Test.HUnit’ Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for 
package ‘HUnit-1.2.5.2’? 
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Then I used the command:

```
cabal install base
```

and I got this message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
base-4.7.0.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

So I used the command:

```
cabal install base -reinstall
```

to reinstall just in case and I got the message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
rejecting: base-4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0,
4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0 (only
already installed instances can be used)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.2 (conflict: base => base>=4.0 && <4.3)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.1 (conflict: base => base>=4.0 && <4.2)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Well, have you installed HUnit yet?

Comment: I have to install it? I thought if i had ghc installed I would have it too

Comment: How can I install it? I just found that I somehow need to use cabal to install some dependencies but they don't explain how to do it

Comment: Haskell is just like any other language - it has libraries and you need to install those libraries to use their functionality..

Comment: Normally `cabal install HUnit` works but you seem to be having some trouble I'm not sure how to resolve. You might get more mileage from installing ghc via installing the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) which includes a good consistent set of packages to get you going. There's a [binary distribution for Ubuntu 12 or 14](https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#binary).

Comment: @AndrewC The GHC version that you are suggesting to install is 7.6.3 but I would like to have 7.8.3 cause there is some minor syntax difference that I got used to. At least that's what i think

Comment: Hmmm. The binary version claims to be `2014.2.0.0`, which has ghc 7.8.3.

Comment: Make a cabal project, add `HUnit` to dependencies, then do `cabal sandbox init && cabal install --only-dependencies && cabal build`. Anyway, constraints on `base` are hell, because its not like you can reinstall `base`. So I'm not sure why people put upper bounds on it, its stupid.

Comment: ummm.. thank you for your comment but I don't know how to make a cabal project or how to add dependencies. Could you give more details?

Comment: @sokras `cabal init` will make the skeleton for the file, and then you just need to set your `Main-is` and `Build-dependencies`

Comment: @alternative how do I set these? a .cabal file was generated but  none of these options is written in the file :/

Comment: @sokras did you select to make an executable?

Comment: @alternative ok i made an executable and the option `main-is` is commented out or something because it is written as `--main-is:`, also is the option `build-depends` the option `Build-dependencies` that you mention in your previous comment? What should I set these two options to?

Comment: @sokras Oops, yea, its `build-depends`. Set `main-is` to whatever your haskell file is, ie, `TestFile.hs`, and set `build-depends` to your list of dependencies, ie, `base, HUnit, ...`

Comment: @alternative after setting these options what do I do ?

Comment: @sokras `cabal sandbox init && cabal install --only-dependencies && cabal build`

Comment: @alternative it says that sandbox is an unrecognised command

Comment: @sokras What version of `cabal install` do you have? Run `cabal --version`

Comment: @alternative cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

Comment: @sokras Didn't you say you are using `ghc-7.8.3`? I would think you would have a more recent cabal if you have that version of `ghc`. Can you update your `cabal` somehow?

Comment: @sokras You should, but normally `cabal` is something you have from your package manager. How did you install all of this stuff in the first place? Having `ghc-7.8.3` and `cabal-1.16` is weird

Comment: @alternative I followed this tutorial: (https://gist.github.com/yantonov/10083524)

Comment: @sokras possibly incorrectly, since it implies that you should get `cabal 1.20.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had mistakenly installed two versions of ghc (7.6.3 and 7.8.3) so I removed them both along with cabal and reinstalled everything. Now it works!